# pip install raises ERROR 13 Permission denied in conda env

Tags: python-3.x, permissions, pip, conda

#### Environment

- MacOS Catalina
- Python 3.7.6
- pip 20.0.2

#### Problem

I've seen article that says when I use pip command in anaconda env, the packages are automatically installed in conda env but when I try use pip including `pip install --upgrade pip` It raises following error

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'RECORD'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

when I type `where pip` it gives me back

```
pip: aliased to pip3
/Users/kimtaegyun/miniconda3/envs/crawling/bin/pip
/Users/kimtaegyun/miniconda3/bin/pip
```

Since the env name is 'crawling' it correctly navigate to my conda env bin folder and the ownership is also correct which is me (not root). Does anyone know how to solve it? If need any extra detail, please let me know.

** UPDATE ** If I use `Path/to/conda/env/pip` instead of pip it works fine. I don't know why correct pip is not used. If anyone know how to see which pip is used, please let me know. (as said above, `where pip` navigate to correct dic and `which pip` gives `pip: aliased to pip3`

Comment: do `conda update pip`, don't use `pip install`

Comment: not only ```pip install --upgrade pip``` sometimes if I need to use pip it's not working.

Comment: are you inside an activated `conda` environment or just the base environment?

Comment: inside activated conda

Comment: what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /Users/kimtaegyun/miniconda3/envs/crawling/bin:/Users/kimtaegyun/miniconda3/bin:/Users/kimtaegyun/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/fzf/bin

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I created a new environment without specifying a Python version or any packages. So something like this

```sh
$ conda create --name empty-env
```

My solution was to include one of the packages in the environment creation command that I knew I was going to install later as a dependency. For me it happened to be

```sh
$ conda create --name not-empty pyopenssl
```

Comment: you put a random package? or what is special about pyopenssl?